# How to solve $ f'(x) = k x \cdot f(x) $

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

The differential equation
$$
f'(x) = k x \cdot f(x)
$$
for $k$ a constant has the solution
$$
f(x) = e^{kx^2/2}.
$$

One way of obtaining the solution is by "inspired guess": by realising that $f'(x)$ refers to $f(x)$ something that involves the exponential function looks reasonable; then use the chain rule in reverse to obtain the factor $kx$ in front of $f(x)$.

How can one obtain the solution in a more rigorous way, e.g. by direct integration?

Comment: **Hint:** Separation of Variables. You have $\displaystyle \int \dfrac{1}{f}~df = \int k x ~dx$.

Comment: You might want to look into integration factors with that line of thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Separation of Variables.

You have:

$$\displaystyle \int \dfrac 1f ~df = \int kx~ dx$$

Answer (score 3):

Reformulating as
$$
0 = f' - k x f = f' + p(x) f 
$$
and then multiplying with an integrating factor 
$$
e^{P(x)}
$$
where $P(x)$ is an antiderivative of $p(x)$ gives
$$
0 = 
f' e^{P(x)} + f e^{P(x)} p(x)
=
\frac{d}{dx}\left( f e^{P(x)} \right)
$$
which resolves to
$$
f = c e^{-P(x)}
$$
for some constant $c$.

Here we have $p(x) = - kx$ and we choose $P(x) = -\frac{k}{2} x^2$ thus
$$
f(x) = c e^{\frac{k}{2}x^2}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Write it as
$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = \ln(f(x))' = k x$$ 
integrate both sides and get 
$$\ln(f(x))=\frac{kx^2}{2}$$
and therefore
$$f(x)=e^{\frac{kx^2}{2}}$$

Comment: Step two introduces a constant of integration.

Answer (score 1):

If $y=f(x)$ then $\frac{dy}{y}=kxdx$. Integrate to obtain $\ln{(y/y_0)}=kx^2/2$ that yields the desired $y(x)=y_0e^{kx^2/2}$.